# Nested select and joins

Tags: sql, firebird

I use the code below to calculate the required information from other tables. I used joins to display Names instead of IDs and to get required sums from other tables. I used `COALESCE` to convert null to Zero.

I had to used it again if I need to sum already COALESCED values, the above code is hard to understand and it's getting harder because I need to add more information, and this is just a small part of the main project so it will be really hard to work with it and will have many error and bugs.

Does it have to be so complicated? Or did I do it wrong? If it has to be complicated like this is there any replacement to get same results with easier way and code? Another RDBMS or anything else?

```
SELECT P.PROJ_ID, P.PROJ_STATUS, P.TYPE_ID, PT.TYPE_NAME, P.CLASS_ID, CLA.CLASS_NAME, P.PROJ_NO, P.PROJ_YEAR, P.PROJ_NAME, P.OLD_PROJ_NAME, 
P.AGENCY_ID, A.AGENCY_NAME, P.CONTRACT_NO, P.CONTRACT_DATE, P.MINISTRY_ID, M.MINISTRY_NAME, 
P.DIRECTORATE_ID, DIR.DIRECTORATE_NAME, 
P.COST, P.ESTIMATED_COST, COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0) AS ADDED_COSTS, (COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)) AS TOTAL_COST, 
P.ALLOCATION, 
COALESCE(EPY.PAST_YEARS, 0) AS PAST_YEARS, 
COALESCE(EF.PAST_MONTHS, 0) AS PAST_MONTHS, 
COALESCE(ECM.CURRENT_MONTH, 0) AS CURRENT_MONTH,
COALESCE(ECY.CURRENT_YEAR, 0) AS CURRENT_YEAR,
COALESCE(E.TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES,

COALESCE(CASH_EPY.CASH_PAST_YEARS, 0) AS CASH_PAST_YEARS, 
COALESCE(CASH_EF.CASH_PAST_MONTHS, 0) AS CASH_PAST_MONTHS, 
COALESCE(CASH_ECM.CASH_CURRENT_MONTH, 0) AS CASH_CURRENT_MONTH,
COALESCE(CASH_ECY.CASH_CURRENT_YEAR, 0) AS CASH_CURRENT_YEAR,
COALESCE(CASH_E.CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0) AS CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES,

COALESCE(TOTAL_E.TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH, 0) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH,

((COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)) - COALESCE(E.TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0)) AS REMAINING,
P.DURATION, COALESCE(DU.ADDED_DURATIONS, 0) AS ADDED_DURATIONS,
(COALESCE(P.DURATION, 0) + COALESCE(DU.ADDED_DURATIONS, 0)) AS TOTAL_DURATION, P.START_DATE, P.FINISH_DATE, 
P.GOVERNORATE_ID, G.GOVERNORATE_NAME, P.PROVINCE_ID, PR.PROVINCE_NAME, P.DISTRICT_ID, D.DISTRICT_NAME, 
P.TOWN_ID, T.TOWN_NAME, 

COALESCE( (E.TOTAL_EXPENSES / (COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)))/100, 0) AS FINANCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT,

P.MATERIAL_ACHIEVEMENT, P.NOTES
FROM PROJECTS P

INNER JOIN PROJECTS_TYPES PT
ON P.TYPE_ID = PT.TYPE_ID

INNER JOIN CLASSES CLA
ON P.CLASS_ID = CLA.CLASS_ID

INNER JOIN AGENCIES A
ON P.AGENCY_ID = A.AGENCY_ID

LEFT JOIN MINISTRIES M
ON P.MINISTRY_ID = M.MINISTRY_ID

LEFT JOIN DIRECTORATES DIR
ON P.DIRECTORATE_ID = DIR.DIRECTORATE_ID

INNER JOIN GOVERNORATES G
ON P.GOVERNORATE_ID = G.GOVERNORATE_ID

LEFT JOIN PROVINCES PR
ON P.PROVINCE_ID = PR.PROVINCE_ID

LEFT JOIN DISTRICTS D
ON P.DISTRICT_ID = D.DISTRICT_ID

LEFT JOIN TOWNS T
ON P.TOWN_ID = T.TOWN_ID

-- ADDED COSTS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(ADDED_VALUE, 0) - COALESCE(REMOVED_VALUE, 0)) as ADDED_COSTS
FROM COSTS
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CO
ON P.PROJ_ID = CO.PROJ_ID

-- EXPENSES FROM PAST YEARS
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as PAST_YEARS
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS EPY
ON P.PROJ_ID= EPY.PROJ_ID

-- EXPENSES FROM PAST MONTHS IN CUREENT YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as PAST_MONTHS
FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)  AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS EF
ON P.PROJ_ID= EF.PROJ_ID

-- EXPENSES FROM CURRENT MONTH AND YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CURRENT_MONTH
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS ECM
ON P.PROJ_ID= ECM.PROJ_ID

-- SUM OF EXPENSES IN CURRENT YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CURRENT_YEAR
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS ECY
ON P.PROJ_ID= ECY.PROJ_ID

-- TOTAL EXPENSES FROM ALL TIME
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as TOTAL_EXPENSES
FROM EXPENSES WHERE CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS E
ON P.PROJ_ID= E.PROJ_ID

-- CASH DEDUCTIONS SUMS
-- CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM PAST YEARS
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_PAST_YEARS
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_EPY
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_EPY.PROJ_ID

-- CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM PAST MONTHS IN CUREENT YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_PAST_MONTHS
FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)  AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_EF
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_EF.PROJ_ID

-- CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM CURRENT MONTH AND YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_CURRENT_MONTH
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_ECM
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_ECM.PROJ_ID

-- SUM OF CASH DEDUCTIONS IN CURRENT YEAR
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_CURRENT_YEAR
  FROM EXPENSES WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_ECY
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_ECY.PROJ_ID

-- TOTAL CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM ALL TIME
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES
FROM EXPENSES WHERE CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_E
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_E.PROJ_ID

-- TOTAL EXPENSES AND CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM ALL TIME
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH
FROM EXPENSES
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS TOTAL_E
ON P.PROJ_ID= TOTAL_E.PROJ_ID

-- ADDED DURATIONS
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(ADDED_VALUE, 0) - COALESCE(REMOVED_VALUE, 0)) as ADDED_DURATIONS
FROM DURATIONS
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS DU
ON P.PROJ_ID= DU.PROJ_ID
ORDER BY P.PROJ_YEAR, P.TYPE_ID, P.PROJ_NO
```

Comment: This is way too much code with a very vague and unspecific question. We are not here to do your job for you. Please ask clearly defined and scoped questions. If you want a code review, consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but make sure to read their rules and expectations first.

Comment: Note that the need to use so many `coalesce` expression might be an indication that your model is wrong. Why do those columns even possibly contain `null`, and not just `0`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know it's too much and I don't want you to do my job,   what I want is to know if my way is right or not and If not then what is the right way to do it, Thank you   It's null because it's imported from other database and it was null there for new inserted data it will be `0` as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be good to start with getting down to just one subquery on the Expenses table. Looks like your coalesces in the sub-queries are just to replace nulls with 0 on 1 column - you could just run an UPDATE to fix that, but if not, I've included a way to do that just once in the example below.

You've got (for example):

```
-- TOTAL CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM ALL TIME
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES
FROM EXPENSES WHERE CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS CASH_E
ON P.PROJ_ID= CASH_E.PROJ_ID

-- TOTAL EXPENSES AND CASH DEDUCTIONS FROM ALL TIME
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0)) as TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH
FROM EXPENSES
GROUP BY PROJ_ID ) AS TOTAL_E
ON P.PROJ_ID= TOTAL_E.PROJ_ID
```

You could do something like this instead:

```
with MY_EXPENSES AS 
   (
   select COALESCE(TOTAL_VALUE, 0) as MY_TOTAL_VALUE, exp.*
   from EXPENSES),

   EXPENSES_SUMMARY AS
   (
   SELECT PROJ_ID,
       sum(case when CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE 
           then MY_TOTAL_VALUE else 0 
           end) as CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES,
       sum(MY_TOTAL_VALUE) as TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH
    FROM MY_EXPENSES
    GROUP BY PROJ_ID )

<Big Query>
LEFT OUTER JOIN EXPENSES_SUMMARY es P.PROJ_ID= TOTAL_E.PROJ_ID
```

Basically take the conditions out of the where clauses in the sub-query and put them in a case statement within a sum - then you can have all 15 or however many it is items from that EXPENSES table in sub-query item. Only have to coalesce the TOTAL_VALUE once instead of in every sub-query.

You could also make a view that does the summary data.

Are there any proj_id's that don't exist at all in EXPENSES, DURATION, or COSTS? If not, then once you make the above change, you shouldn't have to do any COALESCE's in the main query. If so, then you probably still need to replace a few nulls with 0's - could do that client side if you just want to get the coalesce out of the query.

In general, I find the 'with . . . select' more readable for complex queries, but that may just be a preference thing.

Comment: Thanks, I will get ride of null with an UPDATE,   but the main problem is joins to show Names instead of IDs and to get sums, and it give more unwanted columns, and make my code worst

Comment: OK, after too much reading and searching it looks that's how SQL works, there is no better way to do it, I already started using WITH and CASE thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the last code faster and cleaner, thanks to [aduguid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/158032/aduguid) and [dandarc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142702/dandarc)

```
WITH
EXPENSES_SUMS
AS
(
    SELECT 
          PROJ_ID
        , SUM(CASE 
                WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE 
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS PAST_YEARS
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS PAST_MONTHS
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE 
          END) AS CURRENT_MONTH
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS CURRENT_YEAR
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN CASH_DEDUCTIONS = FALSE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS CASH_PAST_YEARS
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)  AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE 
          END) AS CASH_PAST_MONTHS
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS CASH_CURRENT_MONTH
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOC_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS CASH_CURRENT_YEAR
        , SUM(CASE  
                WHEN CASH_DEDUCTIONS = TRUE
                THEN TOTAL_VALUE
          END) AS CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES
        , SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH
        --you can add more columns with your conditions here in case expressions

    FROM 
        EXPENSES
    GROUP BY 
        PROJ_ID
)
, 
COSTS_SUMS
AS
(
    SELECT 
          PROJ_ID
        , SUM(COALESCE(ADDED_VALUE, 0) - COALESCE(REMOVED_VALUE, 0)) AS ADDED_COSTS
        --you can add more columns with your conditions here in case expressions

    FROM 
        COSTS
    GROUP BY 
        PROJ_ID
)
, 
DURATIONS_SUMS
AS
(
    SELECT 
          PROJ_ID
        , SUM(COALESCE(ADDED_VALUE, 0) - COALESCE(REMOVED_VALUE, 0)) AS ADDED_DURATIONS
        --you can add more columns with your conditions here in case expressions

    FROM 
        DURATIONS
    GROUP BY 
        PROJ_ID
)
SELECT 
      P.PROJ_ID
    , P.PROJ_STATUS
    , P.TYPE_ID
    , PT.TYPE_NAME
    , P.CLASS_ID
    , CLA.CLASS_NAME
    , P.PROJ_NO
    , P.PROJ_YEAR
    , P.PROJ_NAME
    , P.OLD_PROJ_NAME
    , P.AGENCY_ID
    , A.AGENCY_NAME
    , P.CONTRACT_NO
    , P.CONTRACT_DATE
    , P.MINISTRY_ID
    , M.MINISTRY_NAME
    , P.DIRECTORATE_ID
    , DIR.DIRECTORATE_NAME
    , P.COST
    , P.ESTIMATED_COST
    , COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0) AS ADDED_COSTS
    , (COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)) AS TOTAL_COST
    , P.ALLOCATION
    , COALESCE(ED.PAST_YEARS, 0) AS PAST_YEARS
    , COALESCE(ED.PAST_MONTHS, 0) AS PAST_MONTHS
    , COALESCE(ED.CURRENT_MONTH, 0) AS CURRENT_MONTH
    , COALESCE(ED.CURRENT_YEAR, 0) AS CURRENT_YEAR
    , COALESCE(ED.TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES
    , COALESCE(ED.CASH_PAST_YEARS, 0) AS CASH_PAST_YEARS
    , COALESCE(ED.CASH_PAST_MONTHS, 0) AS CASH_PAST_MONTHS
    , COALESCE(ED.CASH_CURRENT_MONTH, 0) AS CASH_CURRENT_MONTH
    , COALESCE(ED.CASH_CURRENT_YEAR, 0) AS CASH_CURRENT_YEAR
    , COALESCE(ED.CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0) AS CASH_TOTAL_EXPENSES
    , COALESCE(ED.TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH, 0) AS TOTAL_EXPENSES_CASH
    , ((COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)) - COALESCE(ED.TOTAL_EXPENSES, 0)) AS REMAINING
    , P.DURATION
    , COALESCE(DU.ADDED_DURATIONS, 0) AS ADDED_DURATIONS
    , (COALESCE(P.DURATION, 0) + COALESCE(DU.ADDED_DURATIONS, 0)) AS TOTAL_DURATION
    , P.START_DATE
    , P.FINISH_DATE
    , P.GOVERNORATE_ID
    , G.GOVERNORATE_NAME
    , P.PROVINCE_ID
    , PR.PROVINCE_NAME
    , P.DISTRICT_ID
    , D.DISTRICT_NAME
    , P.TOWN_ID
    , T.TOWN_NAME
    , COALESCE( (ED.TOTAL_EXPENSES / (COALESCE(P.COST, 0) + COALESCE(CO.ADDED_COSTS, 0)))/100, 0) AS FINANCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT
    , P.MATERIAL_ACHIEVEMENT
    , P.NOTES
FROM 
    PROJECTS P
    INNER JOIN PROJECTS_TYPES PT ON P.TYPE_ID = PT.TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN CLASSES CLA ON P.CLASS_ID = CLA.CLASS_ID
    INNER JOIN AGENCIES A ON P.AGENCY_ID = A.AGENCY_ID
    LEFT JOIN MINISTRIES M ON P.MINISTRY_ID = M.MINISTRY_ID
    LEFT JOIN DIRECTORATES DIR ON P.DIRECTORATE_ID = DIR.DIRECTORATE_ID
    INNER JOIN GOVERNORATES G ON P.GOVERNORATE_ID = G.GOVERNORATE_ID
    LEFT JOIN PROVINCES PR ON P.PROVINCE_ID = PR.PROVINCE_ID
    LEFT JOIN DISTRICTS D ON P.DISTRICT_ID = D.DISTRICT_ID
    LEFT JOIN TOWNS T ON P.TOWN_ID = T.TOWN_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXPENSES_SUMS ED ON P.PROJ_ID = ED.PROJ_ID
    LEFT JOIN COSTS_SUMS CO ON P.PROJ_ID = CO.PROJ_ID
    LEFT JOIN DURATIONS_SUMS DU ON P.PROJ_ID = CO.PROJ_ID
ORDER BY 
      P.PROJ_YEAR
    , P.TYPE_ID
    , P.PROJ_NO
```

Comment: Yes, It's now better and if you have any suggests I will be glad to hear it, Thank you.